# how to make the incompatible plugin into compatible plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, redmine-plugins

i am using redmine0.8.2 and rails 2.0.2 . i want the weekly timesheet plugin which is compatible with 1.2.x redmine to install in my redmine.so please anyone guide me to how to do.I have no idea regarding this.

Comment: Upgrade your Redmine install to something modern? 0.8 is around three years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade your redmine or hack the plugin to make it compatible with your old Redmine. First solution advise.